# Does this infinite primes snake-product converge?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, prime-gaps

This re-asks a question I posed on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3087001/237):

> ***Q***. Does this infinite product converge?

$$
\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{7}{5}\cdot\frac{11}{13}\cdot\frac{19}{17}\cdot\frac{23}{29}\cdot\frac{37}{31} \cdot \cdots \;.
$$
I call this the *primes snake-product*:

---

[image: Snake]

---

Out to primes of size $10^{10}$, MSE user @Peter calculated 
the product to be $\approx 0.9048$.

@Wojowu showed that the question is likely difficult,
relying on estimates of alternating sums of prime gaps,
and that perhaps convergence is beyond current knowledge.
I re-pose the question to see if indeed this is the case,
or might known bounds suffice to establish convergence.

Comment: Taking the log and using Bertrand's postulate should give rise to a series whose convergence can be studied more easily.

Comment: Another remark that might or might not be useful : the indices of the primes appearing in the numerators are of the form $4n$ or $4n+1$ hence potentially squares.

Comment: I think you should expect it to converge to zero. The terms alternate between being greater than 1 and less than 1. Taking them in pairs, and considering them as”random variables”, the $n$th random variable should be something like $1\pm 1/\log n$. In similar situations for martingales, such a product should converge almost surely to 0.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas How did you arrive at $1\pm 1/\log n$? Naively, the gap between $p_n$ and $p_{n+1}$ is on average $\log p_n\approx\log n$, so $\frac{p_n}{p_{n+1}}\frac{p_{n+3}}{p_{n+2}}\approx\frac{1}{1+a}\frac{1+a+b+c}{1+a+b}\approx 1+a-c$ where $a,b,c\approx\log n/p_n\approx 1/n$. With $1\pm 1/n$, the product [should converge](https://thatsmaths.com/2016/07/28/random-harmonic-series/).

Comment: Thanks @Wojowu: this was a mental arithmetic error on my part (and your corrected version fits the observed values better).

Comment: @Wojowu: $1+a-c$ or $1-a+c$?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN It should be the latter, good catch. Doesn't make a difference though.